# Rails 5.0 - In-line editing function not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm building an events app on Rails and have comments as a nested resource. So far Users can create and destroy comments but can't edit/update. I'm trying to implement the function using Ajax/ `remote: true` but it's not working. When I click on the edit link nothing happens. Here's what comes up in the development log -

```
Processing by CommentsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"event_id"=>"27", "id"=>"33"}
  [1m[36mComment Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 33], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering comments/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered comments/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 101ms (Views: 88.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Here's the relevant code -

**Comments_controller.rb**

```
# GET /comments/1/edit
    def edit
        @event = @comment.event
        @comment = @event.comments.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |f|
            f.js 
            f.html 
        end
    end

    def show
    end



    def update 
        if @comment.update(comment_params)
            redirect_to @event, notice: "Comment was successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end



    def destroy
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @comment = @event.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy

        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end
```

**edit.js.erb** (I've a feeling this code may be where I'm going wrong)

```
$('#comment').append('<%= j render 'form' %>');
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
<div class="comment clearfix">
  <div class="comment_content">
    <div id="<%=dom_id(comment)%>" class="comment">  
      <p class="comment_name"><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
      <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>

  </div>

      <p><%= link_to 'Edit', [comment.event, comment], id: "comment", remote: true %></p>

                  <p><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.event, comment],
                                     method: :delete,
                                        class: "button",
                              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@event, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>


    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.button :submit, label: 'Add Comment', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Am I identifying the dom ID correctly?

UPDATE - The _comment.html.erb file is rendered on the event/show page -

**show.html.erb - events**

```
            <% if user_signed_in?  %>

                <div id="comments">
                    <h2><%= pluralize @event.comments.count, 'Comment' %></h2>
                    <%= render @event.comments %>


                <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
                        <%= render "comments/form" %>

            <% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: You mean when you click on the edit link, the form doesn't show up?

Comment: Yes, but the js.erb is suppossed to let me edit it on the page, right? Neither are happening at present.

Comment: Ok. I understood the problem. Just tell me from where `_comment.html.erb` is being rendered.

Comment: @Pavan On the event show page - I've updated the question to include this code also.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead i don't see a div with id 'comment' anywhere, only class 'comment'

Comment: @Robbo Is this line where its going wrong - '<div id="<%=dom_id(comment)%>" class="comment"> '

Comment: what do you want to actually happen? clicking an 'edit' link with 'remote: true' isn't what you should be doing. you should just use javascript or jquery to show and hide the form and then the 'remote: true' should be on the update action which re-renders the whole comment partial

Comment: @Robbo I want a user to be able to edit their own comments if they want to on the same page. Looks like I'm miles out.

Comment: @Robbo Trying to avoid using the best_in_place gem...

Comment: i've never heard of that and doesn't seem necessary for this

Comment: @Robbo The gem? There's a railscast on it and yeah, I agree. I thought this would be straightforward. Probably is when you know how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145186/discussion-between-robbo-and-mike-whitehead).